# What is the Fourier transform of $f(x) = x^2 e^{-x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

I have a hand-in for my math course, and don't really know how to attack it. I've seen examples of $x e^{-x^2}$, but can't quite seem to do it with $x^2$.

Comment: If you know how to compute the Fourier transform of $x e^{-x^2}$, just follow the same steps for computing the Fourier transform of $x^2 e^{-x^2}$. Where are you stuck at?

Comment: You should also clarify what are the normalization constants in your definition of Fourier transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $f(x)=x^2e^{-x^2}$ let $g(x)=e^{-x^2}$ with it's Fourier transform is ${\cal F}(g)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-\frac{w^2}{4}}$, then
\begin{align}
g(x) &=e^{-x^2} \\
g'(x) &=-2xe^{-x^2} \\
g''(x) &=4x^2e^{-x^2}-2e^{-x^2} \\
 &=4f(x)-2g(x) \\
{\cal F}(g'')&=4{\cal F}(f)-2{\cal F}(g)\\
-w^2{\cal F}(g)&=4{\cal F}(f)-2{\cal F}(g)\\
{\cal F}(f) &= \dfrac{2-w^2}{4}{\cal F}(g)\\
{\cal F}(f) &= \dfrac{2-w^2}{4}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-\frac{w^2}{4}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

You can use the fact that the Fourier Transform of $x^nf(x)$ is
$$
i^n\frac{d^nF(\omega)}{d \omega^n}
$$

where $F$ is the Fourier transform of $f$ ( and $\omega$ is the angular frequency)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Another method that is more laborious but easier to remember is to use the Taylor expansion:

$$x^2\exp(-x^2)=x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-x^2)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+2}}{n!}.$$

This the problem boils down to determining Fourier transforms of powers. This method might be not the best for this problem but sometimes it is very useful. Especially for Laplace transform this method is very powerful as powers of $x$ or $t$ can be determined very easily for the Laplace transform.

Comment: Power series expansions are awful for Fourier transforms as they get into infinite sums of distributions.

Comment: I know but I wanted to share the method as it might be a useful information to other users.

Comment: So can you actually conclude from this?